# Delphi 10.3.2 TJSON.JsonToObject: AV with empty string array

Tags: delphi

Deserializing json containing an empty string array produces an AV in Delphi 10.3.2, where 10.3.1 did not.

Consider string s, containing:

```
s := { "array": [], "name": "my-test" }
```

and Object:

```
type
  TTestObject = class(TObject)
  private
//    FArray: array of string;
//    FName: string;
  end;
```

then

```
  with TJSON.JsonToObject<TTestObject>(s) do
  try
    ShowMessage('OK');
  finally
    Free;
  end;
```

Results in an AV.
Uncommenting private field FArray or adding an element to the array in the json string results in correct deserialization.
Uncommenting private field FName makes no difference.

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Report the issue at Embarcadero Quality. I could not find a matching issue, only this one https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-23352

Comment: Why are FArray and FName commented out? Uncommenting them makes it work fine, for me

Comment: FArray and FName are commented out to show the issue, which is different handling of an array that is not present in the object and a string varable that is not present in the object. If FName is commented out, no problem, but if FArray must be present, but only when JSON array is empty.